# SQL query not checking for null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this `select * from script_rel where date_mailed is NULL;`

I expect rows in the output which have NULL values in the date_mailed column but i see the following result
[image]

I checked the date values in the result are not null values. Not sure why those zero date values are filtered.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Maybe your UI tool has a bug? Which tool are you using?

Comment: What is the datatype of the date_mailed-column?

Comment: `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` is an invalid timestamp value. (Was however accepted in MySQL 5.6 and older.)

Comment: @jarlh - you can get those 0 dates in there by using `set sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';` .  I still can't reproduce this behavior though...

Comment: @TheImpaler i am using MySQLWorkbench

Comment: @jarlh 5.7.12 is my mysql version

Comment: @slaakso date_miled is of type datetime `date_mailed` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

Comment: What is th output of "select @@sql_mode;"?

Comment: @slaakso i don’t see any output for select @@sql_mode